# Custom UINavigationBar status bar not included background image

Tags: swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar, swift4.1

I'm trying set background image for `UINavigationBar` but status bar always white color

Result

[image]

My code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"bg_nav")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

Expected result image background fill include status bar

[image]

Comment: what exactly your ques is ..?

Comment: @vaibhav I'm added the screenshop of the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Just integrate below function inside your `viewController` where your need to change the status bar appearance.

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
    guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return }
    statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
```

**uses: self.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: *yourColor*)**

*You can apply this to the whole app using common `viewController` and make this `viewController` to the sub class of other viewController's, by usign this approach you dont need to write this code again.*

Comment: But it will be a image and not a color and I know this solution but it is not perfect

Comment: you want to set an image on status bar .. ?

Comment: I want  a background in the UINavigationBar include the status bar

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like that

```
extension UINavigationController{

   func setNavBarImage(_ image:UIImage?) {

       guard let image = image  else {return}

       self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
       self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
      self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

      //clear statusBar color
       let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
       statusBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

> And in ViewController used like that

```
 self.navigationController?.setNavBarImage(UIImage(named: "NavigationBar"))
```

> Result

[image]

Comment: You run on device

Comment: No i'm use simulator